# Can you manually push notifications with appMobi's framework without having to use the admin panel?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, hybrid, appmobi

I am developing a hybrid mobile application with appMobi. So far everything is very promising. From my understanding though it appears that you have to use the admin panel to send push notifications. Is there anyway to manually do this where I can create the mobile applications for clients, and not have to worry about having them signed up with appMobi for the application to function? Essentially I want to pull data from a website, and upon the date of the event execute a push notification that lets the user know an event is going on that day.

Any thoughts or suggestions? I am very new to appMobi's framework, and chose it over Phonegap since I don't have an apple based computer.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can!  Please check out the web service documentation for push messages http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/pushMobi.html